# AVPlayer Frame Rate different from Frame Rate in QuickTime inspector

Tags: avplayer, quicktime, frame-rate

I'm working with AVPlayer and a Quicktime movie I have on my computer.  If I load the Quicktime movie into Apple's Quicktime Player and open the movie inspector, it shows that the movie has a frame rate of 29.97, which is correct.

However when I load the video into AVPlayer and call the following:

```
fps = self.player!.currentItem!.asset.tracks[0].nominalFrameRate
```

it returns a value of 46.875.

I have no idea why.  I know that with interlaced video the nominalFrameRate can return the fields rather than frames, but this is progressive video (non-interlaced) but even if it were interlaced, the field rate would be 59.94.

Note: This only happens with *some* movies.  Not all.  Haven't yet found a common link between the movies which are having this issue.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**  The common link so far seems to be files authored with FCP7, with the exception of a free stock footage clip I downloaded from one of the stock footage sites.  I will have to do more testing to see if there is a link between the codec used.  All of the FCP X files I've tried work as expected.

**EDIT:** This behavior is present with all of the videos I have on my company website (see comments below.)  They are all downloadable for testing from http://www.q-station.com/samples.html

**EDIT:** While I have not confirmed this yet, I believe that videos exported from both FCP7 and FCPX are working correctly.  I'm fairly certain that all of the videos which exhibit this symptom, while they may have originally come from Final Cut, were resized and recompressed after the fact.  I will confirm shortly.

Comment: do you have an example file with a funny frame rate that you can link to here?

Comment: The video file I was working with was a stock footage video file that was a free download, but it wasn't the only file.  So far it seems that all of the files that have been exhibiting this behavior were either clips I downloaded from somewhere else (perhaps not originally authored with quicktime), or were exported from FCP 7.  That's not to say that all FCP7 videos are doing this, only that the files that are came from FCP7.  None of the videos I've exported from FCP X have exhibited this quirk.  I'll find a small file that does this, upload it somewhere and post a link.

Comment: I have several small video files on my website that exhibit this behavior.  If you go to the following:

http://www.q-station.com/samples.html

You can right click on any of the thumbnails and save the movie to your desktop.  I just tested with the bottom one (Welt and Rheaume Commercial).

When opening this movie in Quicktime Player, it shows the correct frame rate of 29.97 fps.

When inspecting via the code above, it shows a frame rate of 43.0664.

No idea why.

Comment: That file really is 29.97fps - I don't know why `nominalFrameRate` is ~1.5x actual frame rate, especially considering that the file is progressive. In its defence, it only claims to be "nominal" or supposed. What do you need the frame rate for exactly?

Comment: Timecode.  I'm working on closed captioning software.  I convert the play time to frames based on the nominal frame rate and use the number of frames from 0 frame to calculate the appropriate SMTPE time code (drop or non-drop).

Comment: Do you have time/bandwidth to calculate the frame rate?

Comment: Have the time, but not the bandwidth.  I suspect that while FinalCut sets this parameter when exporting a video, other conversions may leave it empty.  I'm really only interested in the intended playback frame rate for broadcast video.  I may add a feature that allows the user to override the nominalFrameRate with a given known frame rate in cases where the quicktime movie has a known framerate, but is showing a non-conventional nominal frame rate.  Still curious as to how QuickTime player gets it right... must be pulling it from something other than nominalFrameRate.

Comment: Maybe QuickTime Player isn't 100% `AVFoundation` - maybe it's still using `QTKit` for some things.

Comment: I suppose that's possible.  Haven't worked with QTKit so not familiar with the differences.